# GWT RPC: How could I check insertion of duplicate values from DB into flextable

Tags: java, gwt

I am writing a simple app to enter user into database & display list of users from database using GWT RPC, Hibernate in Eclipse. The problem I am getting is that the list of users is printed twice on client page.

The reason I found is that as getUser method(i.e. print list) is called on each new entry so that new entries could populate into FlexTable on client page, all entries are populated every time rather. How can I put a check so that only new entries are populated when method is called. OR what could be a better way to achieve what I am trying to do.

Here is my entryPoint code:

```
package rpctest.client;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import rpctest.shared.User;
import rpctest.shared.FieldVerifier;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickHandler;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyCodes;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyPressEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyUpEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyUpHandler;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Window;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.DialogBox;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FlexTable;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HTML;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HorizontalPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Label;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TextBox;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.VerticalPanel;

import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyCodes;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyPressEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyPressHandler;

/**
 * Entry point classes define <code>onModuleLoad()</code>.
 */
public class Rpctest implements EntryPoint {

    final TextBox firstName = new TextBox();
    final TextBox lastName = new TextBox();
    final Button ans = new Button("Add User");
    //final Label label1 = new Label("First Name");
    //final Label label2 = new Label("Last Name");
    private FlexTable userFlexTable = new FlexTable();
    //final Label errorLabel = new Label();

    private VerticalPanel mainpanel = new VerticalPanel();
    private HorizontalPanel addpanel1 = new HorizontalPanel();
    private HorizontalPanel addpanel2 = new HorizontalPanel();
    private final RpctestServiceAsync callService = GWT
            .create(RpctestService.class);

    /**
     * This is the entry point method.
     */
    public void onModuleLoad() {

        userFlexTable.setText(0, 0, "ID");
        userFlexTable.setText(0, 1, "First Name");
        userFlexTable.setText(0, 2, "Second Name");
        userFlexTable.setText(0, 3, "Remove");

        //add input boxes to panel
        addpanel1.add(firstName);
        addpanel1.add(lastName);

        firstName.setFocus(true);

        //add input/result panels 
        mainpanel.add(userFlexTable);
        mainpanel.add(addpanel1);
        addpanel1.add(ans);

        ans.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                        addStock();                 
            }
        });

        lastName.addKeyPressHandler(new KeyPressHandler() {
              public void onKeyPress(KeyPressEvent event) {
                  if (event.getCharCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER) {
                      addStock();
                  }
                }
              });

        RootPanel.get().add(mainpanel);
        //getUser();
    }

private void addStock(){

        String name1 = firstName.getValue();
        // Stock code must be between 1 and 10 chars that are numbers, letters, or dots.
        /*if (!name1.matches("^[0-9A-Z\\.]{1,10}$")) {
          Window.alert("'" + name1 + "' is not a valid name.");
          firstName.selectAll();
          return;
        }*/
         firstName.setValue("");

        String name2 = lastName.getValue();
        /*if (!name2.matches("^[0-9A-Z\\.]{1,10}$")) {
              Window.alert("'" + name1 + "' is not a valid name.");
              lastName.selectAll();
              return;
            }*/
        lastName.setValue("");
        firstName.setFocus(true);

        callService.addUser(name1,name2,
            new AsyncCallback<String>() {
            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                // Show the RPC error message to the user
                    Window.alert("check your inputs");
                }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String result) {
               //  TODO Auto-generated method stub
               //  Add the user to the table.
               //  int row = userFlexTable.getRowCount();
               //  userFlexTable.setText(row, 1, result);
                   getUser();
            }
        });
    }

private void getUser(){

    callService.getUser(new AsyncCallback<User[]>() {
            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                // Show the RPC error message to the user
                    Window.alert("Problem in database connection");
                }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(User[] result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i ++)
                    {
                     //String s = result[i].getFirstName();               
                     int row = userFlexTable.getRowCount();
                     userFlexTable.setText(row, 0, result[i].getId().toString());
                     userFlexTable.setText(row, 1, result[i].getFirstName());
                     userFlexTable.setText(row, 2, result[i].getLastName());
                        }                       

            }
        });

      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain if this will work or not, but is it possible to use Session variables and then apply logic based upon the Session state?  For instance, the first time getUser() is called, a Session variable could be set indicating it had been called and then logic could be implemented to check if that Session variable has been set or not in subsequent calls...
Kind of thinking out loud but it seems that using Session state might help...

Comment: thank you very much Zack: I am thinking kind of same thing but not yet been able to find a logic i.e. code to do that .....